# iOS source CanvasKit

Tags: ios

I'm new in iOS development and a I found Github, where I found some sources which can help me very much.

> https://github.com/jasonmorrissey/CanvasKit

When I opened this project, I run it on a simulator, and I saw that, in the project there are  2 targets (one  like usual and the other one is a "kit"). I wanna run this to understand exactly the steps from the code and breakpoint this code. Somebody can help me to open/run this source please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the target in the upper left corner of xcode ( next to the Run button) In order to run the demo you need the static library (see the build phases -> link binary with libraries) . In order to get the static library you will first need to build it by selecting the CanvasKit target. You will get 3 errors when you will do that , regarding two setter methods. Go in the respective .h file and make those properties `nonatomic` and `readwrite`. 
Then you will be able to build the library and after that you can build the demo.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The kit is a static library. There's no need to run it besides you want to use that lib in a different project.

I think no one will help you studying the whole code. Get comfortable with obj-c and if you've got some specific questions you're free to ask.